# Tensorflow: KL divergence for a Gaussian Mixure

Tags: python, tensorflow, gaussian, gmm, mixture

I know with python and **scikit learn**, how to calculate **KL** divergence for **Gaussian mixture** given that its parameters such as weight, mean, and covariance as **np.array**,as shown below.

[GaussianMixture initialization using component parameters - sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392887/gaussianmixture-initialization-using-component-parameters-sklearn)

[KL-Divergence of two GMMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079881/kl-divergence-of-two-gmms)

But I am wondering, with **Tensorflow**, is there any way to calculate **KL** divergence between two **Gaussian mixture** given that its parameters as  **Tensor**,

1) I tried scikit above in Tensorflow, but it didn't work since Tensorflow doens'T give it a actual values until session is executed.

2) There are some TF packages, but not exactly KL for Gaussian mixture.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/Mixture

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/kl_divergence

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Later, I tried with a latest TF library as below.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print('tensorflow ',tf.__version__)  # for Python 3
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = tf.contrib.distributions
kl_divergence=tf.contrib.distributions.kl_divergence

# Gaussian Mixure1
mix = 0.3# weight
bimix_gauss1 = ds.Mixture(
cat=ds.Categorical(probs=[mix, 1.-mix]),#weight
components=[
   ds.Normal(loc=-1., scale=0.1),
   ds.Normal(loc=+1., scale=0.5),
])

# Gaussian Mixture2
mix = 0.4# weight
bimix_gauss2 = ds.Mixture(
    cat=ds.Categorical(probs=[mix, 1.-mix]),#weight
    components=[
    ds.Normal(loc=-0.4, scale=0.2),
    ds.Normal(loc=+1.2, scale=0.6),
])

# KL between GM1 and GM2
kl_value=kl_divergence(
    distribution_a=bimix_gauss1,
    distribution_b=bimix_gauss2,
    allow_nan_stats=True,
    name=None
)

sess = tf.Session() # 
with sess.as_default():

    x = tf.linspace(-2., 3., int(1e4)).eval()
    plt.plot(x, bimix_gauss1.prob(x).eval(),'r-')
    plt.plot(x, bimix_gauss2.prob(x).eval(),'b-')
    plt.show()

    print('kl_value=',kl_value.eval())
```

Then I got this error...
**NotImplementedError: No KL(distribution_a || distribution_b) registered for distribution_a type Mixture and distribution_b type Mixture**

I am very sad now. :(

Comment: Have you tried tensorflow's eager execution? Numpy-style code should easily translate there.

Comment: no, I was not aware of that. I will try, let you know how it works. thank you!

Comment: @JimSD were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @JimSD; I'm also interesting in implement an algorithm involving this, have you figure it out yet?